# cannot open old Unity 5.6.1 project

Tags: unity-game-engine, version-control

I was just given a pretty old unity project, and am trying to open it.
These are the versions I am using:

```
PC: macOS Monterey 12.4
Unity HUB: 3.3.0
Unity: 5.6.1f1 + Android Build Support
```

I try opening the project, but nothing happens.
On the first few tries a black window would open, but now only the icon appears on the Dock.
There is no signs of any error messages, and the same goes for the logs file...

```
{"timestamp":"2022-09-15T07:43:22.167Z","level":"info","moduleName":"LaunchProcess","message":"[ 'child process exited with code 0' ]"}
{"timestamp":"2022-09-15T07:43:25.101Z","level":"info","moduleName":"LaunchProcess","message":"[ 'child process exited with code 0' ]"}
{"timestamp":"2022-09-15T07:43:26.103Z","level":"info","moduleName":"LicensingSdkService","message":"[ 'checkEntitlements: checking entitlements for: com.unity.editor.ui' ]"}
{"timestamp":"2022-09-15T07:43:26.120Z","level":"info","moduleName":"LicensingSdkService","message":"[ 'Successfully checked for entitlements request.' ]"}
{"timestamp":"2022-09-15T07:43:26.122Z","level":"info","moduleName":"LocalProjectService","message":"[\n  'openProject projectPath: /Users/apple/Documents/Unity/Really_Old_File_0815_DB, current editor:',\n  undefined\n]"}
{"timestamp":"2022-09-15T07:43:26.123Z","level":"info","moduleName":"RestEvent:Project","message":"[\n  'onProjectOpen data:',\n  {\n    projectPath: '/Users/apple/Documents/Unity/Really_Old_File_0815_DB',\n    normalizedProjectPath: '/Users/apple/Documents/Unity/Really_Old_File_0815_DB'\n  }\n]"}
{"timestamp":"2022-09-15T07:43:26.123Z","level":"info","moduleName":"LicensingSdkService","message":"[ 'checkEntitlements: checking entitlements for: com.unity.editor.ui' ]"}
{"timestamp":"2022-09-15T07:43:26.134Z","level":"info","moduleName":"LicensingSdkService","message":"[ 'Successfully checked for entitlements request.' ]"}
{"timestamp":"2022-09-15T07:43:26.134Z","level":"info","moduleName":"LaunchProcess","message":"[\n  'Spawning editor instance with command: ',\n  '/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/5.6.1f1/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity',\n  ', and arguments: ',\n  [\n    '-projectpath',\n    '/Users/apple/Documents/Unity/Really_Old_File_0815_DB',\n    '-useHub',\n    '-hubIPC',\n    '-cloudEnvironment',\n    'production',\n    '-licensingIpc',\n    'LicenseClient-apple',\n    '-hubSessionId',\n    '5b1d8bd0-34a3-11ed-9490-cb13c39bed2b'\n  ]\n]"}
{"timestamp":"2022-09-15T07:43:26.606Z","level":"info","moduleName":"LicensingSdkService","message":"[ 'Get all entitlement groups' ]"}
{"timestamp":"2022-09-15T07:43:26.621Z","level":"info","moduleName":"LicensingSdkService","message":"[ 'Successfully received all entitlement groups details' ]"}
{"timestamp":"2022-09-15T07:43:26.622Z","level":"info","moduleName":"LicensingSdkService","message":"[ 'Received 1 entitlement groups' ]"}
{"timestamp":"2022-09-15T07:43:26.622Z","level":"info","moduleName":"LicensingSdkService","message":"[ 'Get all entitlement groups' ]"}
{"timestamp":"2022-09-15T07:43:26.637Z","level":"info","moduleName":"LicensingSdkService","message":"[ 'Successfully received all entitlement groups details' ]"}
{"timestamp":"2022-09-15T07:43:26.637Z","level":"info","moduleName":"LicensingSdkService","message":"[ 'Received 1 entitlement groups' ]"}
```

Does anyone have any clues as to what the issue might be?
Or any tips as to where I should be looking to find the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It opened just fine on Windows.
I am guessing this means that `Unity 5.6.1` and macOS are incompatible?